# Error when storing names with ñ in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel throws the following error when I try to store records that contain 'ñ' and '´':

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE3\xB1es' for column 'names' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `clients` (`cedula`, `names`, `email`) values (5454545, Pablito Nu�es, email@dominio.com))
```

The database is in utf8_general_ci, as well as the html.

I used this mutator:

```
public function setNamesAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['names'] = strtr($value, 'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ', 'aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');

    }
```

But it stores it as "YA" instead of "n".

Any advice on how to solve this?

ps: I'm using laragon and laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `utf8mb4` character set. Additionally you need to set connection charset to utf8mb4. So change `'charset'` in ***config/database.php*** to `'utf8mb4'`.

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
```

For example:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    'prefix' => 'pre_',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Comment: I updated my answer and suggest to use `utf8mb4` charset.

Comment: at the beginning I worked with utf8mb4, then I changed to UTF-8.
What seems strange to me is that it accepts only "Ñ" and not the "ñ"